# How to compile a vb.net project with microsoft access database so that it can be opened on other machine

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access-2007

can someone please tell me on how to compile a vb.net project along with microsoft access database so that it can be opened in other machines? i tried to build it but when i try to open the application on other machine it tells an error that it cannot find the location of the database file, but i pasted it on the vb.net project folder. in my own machine it works perfectly. also i did the Publish, but it shows the same error. to summarize it, i want it to be standalone. sorry for my noob question, but i really need an answer. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining connectionString for remotely hosted SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121542/defining-connectionstring-for-remotely-hosted-sql-server)

Comment: Add the mdb to your project and set it to 'always copy'.

Comment: How can i add the database file and to set it to 'always copy'?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, can you simply make sure that the Access file is in the same folder as the EXE, and then programatically set the path?

Get path this way:

```
Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
```

Open Database:

```
Dim MDBConnString_ As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPath & "\MyDB.accdb;"
Dim cnn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(MDBConnString_)
```